# TPL with multiple Method calls Console.Write issue

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, console-application

If i use TPL i run into problems in Parse.. Methods i do use Console.Write to build some Line but somtimes one is to fast and writes in the other Methods row. How do i lock or is there some better way?

```
Parallel.Invoke(
  () => insertedOne = Lib.ParseOne(list),
  () => insertedTwo = Lib.ParseTwo(list),
  () => insertedThree = Lib.ParseThree(list));
```

Example for Parse.. Methods.

```
public static int ParseOne(string[] _list) {
    Console.Write("blabla");
    Console.Write("blabla");
    return 0;
}
public static int ParseTwo(string[] _list) {
    Console.Write("hahahah");
    Console.Write("hahahah");
    return 0;
}
public static int ParseThree(string[] _list) {
    Console.Write("egegege");
    Console.Write("egegege");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information.  What is `Lib`, what is `ParseOne`, `ParseTwo`, and `ParseThree`.  What are their signatures?  What context are you using this?  What is your current output versus your expected output?

Comment: If multiple threads share a resource, then you need to employ some kind of synchronization if you want to control the outcome. The console is a shared resource in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to print your `blabla`s, `hahahah`s and `egegege`s as a single entity(indivisible)
you can write your method as:

```
public static int ParseThree(string[] _list)
{
    lock (Console.Out)
    {
        Console.Write("egegege");
        Console.Write("egegege");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you run all the tasks in one thread, one after the other?

```
 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
 {
    insertedOne = Lib.ParseOne(list);
    insertedTwo = Lib.ParseTwo(list);
    insertedThree = Lib.ParseThree(list);
 });
```

This way you won't have that much of a race condition.

Comment: `Why don't you run all the tasks in one thread, one after the other?` Maybe `Lib.ParseXXX`s are costly operations and OP wants to execute them in parallel.

Comment: You start a task which executes the methods sequentialy and doesn't wait  them to complete. Not close to what OP tries to achieve.

Comment: Mhmmm working with what I saw, you could always start three seperate tasks and call task(n-1).Wait() before you return the results of the tasks?

Comment: i ve added some more example at top actually just would like that no blablahahahah happen for example. I wont lose performance with waiting for finishing the whole method maybe i can just lock this 2 Console.Write().. instructions together in each method?

Comment: lock doesn't ensure ordering (ie isn't FIFO), so locking won't work 100% of the time for printing it in the correct order.